# Try upload videofile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I use Laravel 5.4 and I try upload video file. Image file upload successfully.

```
$video = Request::file('video_file')) {
        $fullName = 'videos/'.uniqid().time().'.'.$video->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk()->put($fullName, $video);
```

But it didn't work. When I try get information about file - `size = 0`

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a limit on the amount of data you can send in a POST request. If you exceed that limit, PHP will return zero as the size of the file.

Instead, you’ll need to upload the file in chunks. If you’re using something like Amazon Web Services, they have a JavaScript SDK that will handle multi-part uploads for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size 
PHP has a default max_post_size of 8mb I believe, anything larger than that will not go through. There is also a upload_max_filesize that you may want to check out. I'm not sure if increasing the limit is the correct answer here, as I'm not sure what complications that would bring. When we upload large Files we use blue imp's file uploader: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
It's pretty straight forward and automatically chunks the uploads for you.